# Achieving high throughput when inserting data into Neo4J database from Kafka topics using Kafka Sink connector

Tags: apache-kafka, neo4j, apache-kafka-connect

I am inserting records from kafka topics into neo4j database, and using these records I'm creating nodes and relationships in the database. I'm using Neo4j sink connector for it. Currently, I'm able to achieve throughput of 10k records/sec where each record is about 100 Bytes size.
I want to increase the throughput further but have few questions,

1. How can we find the maximum achievable throughput of Kafka cluster and Neo4j database based on their system properties, configuration parameters and size of records?
2. Which parameters of both kafka cluster and neo4j, govern the throughput of the system?
3. Is it possible to achieve very high throughput by still maintaining ACID properties and avoiding duplication of Nodes and relationships?

My Neo4j Sink connector is configured as below:

```
{
"name":"neo4j-sink-connector",
"config":{
  "connector.class": "streams.kafka.connect.sink.Neo4jSinkConnector",
  "topics": "topic-main",
  "tasks.max": 4,
  "group.id": "neo4j-consumer",
  "neo4j.batch.size":30000,
  "max.poll.records":30000,
  "max.partition.fetch.bytes":3097152,
  "auto.offset.reset": "latest",
  "kafka.key.deserializer": "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer",
  "kafka.value.deserializer": "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer",
  "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
  "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
  "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
  "errors.retry.timeout": "-1",
  "errors.retry.delay.max.ms": "1000",
  "errors.tolerance": "all",
  "errors.log.enable": true,
  "errors.log.include.messages": true,
  "neo4j.server.uri": "xxxxxxx",
  "neo4j.authentication.basic.username": "xxxxxx",
  "neo4j.authentication.basic.password": "xxxxxxx",
  "neo4j.topic.cypher.topic-main": "MERGE (u: User {Name: event.Name_1, Source: 'xyz'}) MERGE (v:User {Name:event.Name_2, Source: 'xyz'}) MERGE (u)-[:TimeStamp {TimeStamp: event.TimeStamp, Source: 'xyz'}]->(v) "}
}
```